# String concatenation using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

How do I achieve concatenation using only pointers since the code below gives (a segmentation fault) error (at runtime)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *s1="Front";
    char *s2="Back";
    char *s3=strcat(s1,s2);
    puts(s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to write to a string literal. The line `char *s1 = "Front";` points to a string constant, which can't be written to.

Change it to `char s1[20] = "Front";` and it should work out like you expect - as long as you are adding no more than 14 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Read about what `strcat` does, keeping in mind that literal strings (such as `"Front"` and `"Back"`) are not modifiable.

Answer (score 1):

You need space for the result, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *s1="Front";
    char *s2="Back";
    char s3[80];
    s3[0] = '\0';
    strcat(s3,s1);
    strcat(s3,s2);
    puts(s3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you initialize s3[0]=0?? Sorry if it's a naive question!

Comment: `strcat()` adds data to the end of a null-terminated string; the `s3[0] = '\0';` ensures that `s3` is an empty null-terminated string before the concatenations start.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I believe my code would have compiled just fine.  Don't feel like going to K+R to find the reference right now tho.

Comment: It would, but it is clearer to use `'\0'` to mean the null byte in character strings and reserve 0 for bigger integers.  Your choice; you can return it to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The code gives an error because concatenating `s1` with `s2` will require the allocated memory for `s1` to be >= the combined lengths of the two byte arrays. `strcat` will attempt to iterate over memory that wasn't assigned to `s1`, thus causing a runtime error. The only way this will work through pointers is if you make `str3` a char array where the size is known at compile time (or a pointer to a dynamically-allocated one for runtime):

```
char s1[10] = "Front";
char *s2 = "Back";

char *s3 = strcat(s1, s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way too. Though it is not better than strcat() but it is implemented using pointers only.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 20
void concat(char *,char *);

int main()
{
    char string1[SIZE]="\0",string2[SIZE]="\0";

    printf("Enter String 1:\n");
    gets(string1);
    printf("Enter String 2:\n");
    gets(string2);

    concat(string1,string2);

    return 0;
}
void concat(char *str1,char *str2)
{
    char *conc=str1;

    while(*str1!='\0')
        str1++;

    *str1=' ';
    ++str1;

    while(*str2!='\0')
    {
        *str1=*str2;
        str1++,str2++;
    }

    *str1='\0';
    printf("Concatenated String:\n");
    puts(conc);

}
```